# How can I validate a phone number using a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

In my exercise I'm supposed to validate phone numbers, which of the correct are :

```
1234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
(123)456-7890
(123) 456-7890
456-7890
```

I've tried `[(]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][).-]? ?[0-9][0-9][0-9][.-]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`, but it seems  it also accepts something like `(123.456-7890`. How I can handle this? Or I should take completely different way ?

Here are some invalid phone numbers:

```
123-45-6789
123:4567890
123/456-7890
```

Comment: You should show incorrect too, otherwise `.*` is a correct answer

Comment: Ah, I've grappled with this problem before. It wouldn't be a bad idea to clearly outline the set of correct and incorrect inputs (for instance, I notice you can mix space and dash seperators, but not dots and brackets?)

Comment: @ashur, I believe that I meet all of your requirements.  I edited my post and tried to explain in as much detail as possible.  Hope it's helpful.

Comment: The accepted answer of the Qn your Qn has been marked as a dup of doesn't solve it by regex.Please, have a look at my soln. I had tested all the negative test cases as well that you found passing on other solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (using look-aheads to match parenthesis and other balance checks):

```
^(?:((?=\(.*\).*\-)|(?!.*\()(?!.*\)))\(?[0-9]{3}\)?(((?<=[)])|[\-\s])(?=.*\-)|\.(?=.*\.)|(?<=^)|(?=[0-9]+$)))?[0-9]{3}[\s.-]?[0-9]{4}$
```

Or this one <sup>(using `\d` as this is my contestant to the shortest-regex parade)</sup>:

```
^((\d{3}-|\(\d{3}\)\s?)?\d{3}-|^\d{3}(\.)?\d{3}\3)\d{4}$
```

Comment: I prefer using `\d` as opposed to `[0-9]`. Nice edit also.

Comment: @JavaDevil Yeah, I do too. The thing is `\d` can match unicode digits as well. If that's not a worry, the regex would certainly look prettier with `\d` :)

Comment: Wait does this also handle the awkward scenario of `123.456-7890` where  the separator between the numbers has to be consistent? I feel that's the challenging aspect of this question...

Comment: Hmmm.. it looks like it also accepts `(123)456.7890` which is not precised to be correct or incorrect in my exercise.

Comment: @aug There you guys go. Getting prettier and prettier. :)

Comment: @acdcjunior - If that's pretty, I'd hate to see ugly...

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed for OP but it worked for `123-4567891` and `123456-7891`. I have to say though, you are a sorcerer. http://i.imgur.com/UQ15dEA.png

Comment: Updated! It passes all known tests.  @aug, Can you guys check it out? I will leave the explaining part for when it works.

Comment: @ashur Have you tried this last version?

Comment: @acdcjunior I've just checked and it does not validate `1234567890`. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: How are you using them? They do validate `1234567890`. See: http://regexr.com?35ck4

Answer (score -1):

This pattern works with your examples, i write it without the java escapes:

```
 ^(?>\(\d{3}\) ?|\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

Explanations:

```
 ^                 begining  of the string
 (?>               open an atomic group
    \(\d{3}\) ?    3 digits with parenthesis followed by a space or not
   |               OR
    \d{3}[.-]      3 digits followed by . or - or not
 )                 close atomic group
 ?                 the atomic group is optional
 \d{3}             3 digits
 [.-]?             followed by a . or a - (optional)
 \d{4}             4 digits
 $                 end of the string
```

Answer (score -1):

**Regex**

```
^\d{10}|^(\(\d{3}\)\s?)?\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}([.-])\d{3}\2\d{4}$
```

*Matches the following*

```
1234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
(123)456-7890
(123) 456-7890
456-7890
```

*Does not match on*

```
123-45-6789
123:4567890
123/456-7890
(123-456-7890
123.456-7890
(123)456.7890
```